OData 4.01 and Saleforce, create an endpoint for a datasource used by an external lookup
I am trying to create an external lookup in Salesforce, setting up a datasource, connected to an API endpoint, which I need to provide. I read that I need to use the OData format. If I am not mistaken the last available version is the 4.01, which should be supported by Salesforce.
I read the documentation, and looked at the format, but I can't find any useful examples. I have created a dummy endpoint returning a few campaigns. At the moment it returns a JSON looking like this:
{
  [
    {"campaign_id": "000001", "name": "The butterfly"}, 
    {"campaign_id": "000002", "name": "Oranges and apples"}
  ]
}

And of course it does not work. I would like to return a proper JSON (or whatever), according to OData 4.01 (or one format suitable for Salesforce).
I can't manage to find any useful examples. Can you provide me with one? I tried ChatGPT, but I am not sure the output provided is the correct one.
